# Python + FastAPI + Gunicorn + Nginx + Oracle Cloud VM, website not showing

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn, fastapi, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I followed these 2 articles: [Article 1](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-python-apis-to-the-web-with-linux-2f4c7be8a76d),  [Article 2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04) to setup my Python Fast API project.

Followed these 2 articles, I installed Gunicorn and Ngnix on the VM from Oracle Cloud.

Here are my configuration files:

> /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/maze
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 4 \
          -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker \
          -b unix:gunicorn.sock \
          -m 007 \
          --timeout 1200 \
          main:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/gunicorn.conf

```
server {
listen 8000;
server_name 168.138.12.192;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

> /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

then I ran the following commands, to make sure the changes take effective

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn.service
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl restart nginx

sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.service
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl enable nginx
```

Also ran

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service
```

to make sure the service is up and running. It looks good to me:

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-05-23 02:47:59 UTC; 10s ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
   Main PID: 4142 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 13 (limit: 1107)
     Memory: 339.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
             ├─4142 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b unix:/run/gunicorn.sock -m 007 --timeout 1200 m>
             ├─4153 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b unix:/run/gunicorn.sock -m 007 --timeout 1200 m>
             ├─4154 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b unix:/run/gunicorn.sock -m 007 --timeout 1200 m>
             ├─4157 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b unix:/run/gunicorn.sock -m 007 --timeout 1200 m>
             └─4159 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b unix:/run/gunicorn.sock -m 007 --timeout 1200 m>

May 23 02:48:08 instance-20210520-2215 gunicorn[4154]: [2021-05-23 02:48:08 +0000] [4154] [INFO] Application startup complete.
May 23 02:48:08 instance-20210520-2215 gunicorn[4157]: [2021-05-23 02:48:08 +0000] [4157] [INFO] Started server process [4157]
May 23 02:48:08 instance-20210520-2215 gunicorn[4157]: [2021-05-23 02:48:08 +0000] [4157] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
May 23 02:48:08 instance-20210520-2215 gunicorn[4157]: [2021-05-23 02:48:08 +0000] [4157] [INFO] Application startup complete.
May 23 02:48:08 instance-20210520-2215 gunicorn[4153]: [2021-05-23 02:48:08 +0000] [4153] [INFO] Started server process [4153]
May 23 02:48:08 instance-20210520-2215 gunicorn[4153]: [2021-05-23 02:48:08 +0000] [4153] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
May 23 02:48:08 instance-20210520-2215 gunicorn[4153]: [2021-05-23 02:48:08 +0000] [4153] [INFO] Application startup complete.
May 23 02:48:08 instance-20210520-2215 gunicorn[4159]: [2021-05-23 02:48:08 +0000] [4159] [INFO] Started server process [4159]
May 23 02:48:08 instance-20210520-2215 gunicorn[4159]: [2021-05-23 02:48:08 +0000] [4159] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
May 23 02:48:08 instance-20210520-2215 gunicorn[4159]: [2021-05-23 02:48:08 +0000] [4159] [INFO] Application startup complete.
```

then I ran this command to see whether I am able to see the correct website on the VM

```
curl http://localhost:8000
```

I did see my website got returned.

BUT, when I try to access the website from my browser by the following IP addresses:

```
http://http://168.138.12.192/
```

I can see the default nginx website

```
http://168.138.12.192:8000/
```

Firefox shows me Unable to connect

**What am I missing??**

Comment: gosh, I messed up configurations and curl 8000 stopped working, luckily I have posted what I have done previously here and once followed what I posted here, I was able to bring back the working localhost:8000 .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I need to also alter the firewall rule to open port 8000, although I have added the Ingress rule to pen port 8000

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```